# No Line Break With jQuery .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, text-alignment

I'm parsing a XML using jQuery with the following code:

```
function appendNav(xml) {
    $(xml).find("Nav").each(function() {
        $("#navBar").append("<a id='navItem' href='" + $(this).find("Link").text() + "'>" + $(this).attr("name") + "</a>");
        $("#navBar").append("<div class='navItemSep'> | </div>");
    });

    $(".navItemSep").filter(":last").remove();
}
```

And using the following XML:

```
<Navbar>
    <Nav name="Home">
        <Link>index.html</Link>
    </Nav>
    <Nav name="Twitter">
        <Link>http://twitter.com/nathanpc</Link>
    </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

The problem is that I'm getting this on multiple lines instead of only a single one. What I need to do to make it output this on a single line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the `div` to a `span`

Comment: yes, by default divs are block-level, meaning they'll clear the element before it and start on a 'new line' so-to-speak.