# jQuery append text while maintain height and hiding previous text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this div, its contents are from jquery append():

[image]

Each time the text length reaches end of div width, the text will keep going and changing the div's height.

But I want to maintain div's height and hiding previous text. Also, I have a PNG with gradient and I want to put the png image to the left when jquery append detected the div has been full with text.

Expected result:

[image]

What I've been tried:

1. https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-do-you-put-a-div-without-causing-a-new-line-break/7398/8
2. [No Line Break With jQuery .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481941/no-line-break-with-jquery-append)

My current code (javascript):

```
$.post(base_url + "ajax/validate_answer", {'quiz': load, 'answer': answer}, function (data) {

    /* if incorrect answer */
    if (data.answer_details.correct === false)
    {
        $("." + current_did).css("color", "#D05555");
    }

    /* append text with a new word */
    $(".dictionary-stack").append(' &nbsp; &#8226; &#8226; &#8226; &nbsp; <span class="' + data.next_quiz.display.dictionary.did + '">' + data.next_quiz.display.dictionary.ja_kanji + ' ' + data.next_quiz.display.dictionary.ja_roman + ' [' + data.next_quiz.display.dictionary.en_roman + ']</span>');
}
```

CSS to the container (.dictionary-stack):

```
.dictionary-stack
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:100px;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    background:#E6E6E6;
    padding: 20px;
    color:#333333;
}
```

How I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably got a downvote on this question because it does not show any research effort on the issue. Please provide the code you have written and a specific question on a particular technical issue you are having with it.

Comment: Question edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML/CSS, it is difficult to deliver a solution for your exact case.

As you know, your text is wrapping and that is causing the div to increase in height.

You can use some of these CSS properties to discover the correct solution for your case:

height:30px (i.e. a fixed height),

width:200% (i.e. a width that will not wrap),

overflow:hidden (to hide overflowed text when used with a fixed height)

```js
/*
In the example below, you need the `#container` div so that you can use `overflow:hidden` on it -- to suppress the horizontal scrollbar. Without this div (and its overflow:hidden css instruction) the horizontal scrollbar will appear on the body - and that is more difficult to suppress.

*/
```

```css
#container{overflow:hidden;}

#normal{background:wheat;margin-bottom:20px;}

#allowOverflow {position:relative;left:-400%;width:500%;height:25px;overflow:hidden;text-align:right;background:palegreen;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="normal">
Once upon a midnight dreary, While I pondered weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore. While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping - as of someone gently rapping - rapping on chamber door. 'Tis some visitor, I muttered, rapping on my chamber door. Merely that and nothing more.
</div>

<div id="allowOverflow">
Once upon a midnight dreary, While I pondered weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore. While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping - as of someone gently rapping - rapping on chamber door. 'Tis some visitor, I muttered, rapping on my chamber door. Merely that and nothing more.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: From your answer, the #allowOverflow shows "Once upon a midnight dreary...". What I targeting is #allowOverflow showing "...Merely that and nothing more." while "Once upon a midnight dreary..." is hidden like putting -left:-999999.

Comment: Sure, that can be solved by using **`position:relative;left:-400%;width:500%;text-align:right`**. *You want the field to display as 100% of the container width, and you also want the text to overflow as much as 5x screen width. The above handles that nicely.* ***See updated example in my above answer***

Answer (score 0):

My idea to solve this problem is:

- on document ready compute the height and save as attribute
- before append set opacity to 0
- append text
- after 50 milliseconds start checking the new height: while it is greater the
  the original start removing (saving) the chars from the beginning of the div

The snippet (for the demo I used a different url):

```js
var txt = $(".dictionary-stack").text();
var interval;
$(".dictionary-stack").text('a').attr('data-height', $(".dictionary-stack").outerHeight()).text(txt);
$('#myBtn').on('click', function (e) {
  $.get('https://api.github.com/repositories', {'since': 364}, function (data) {
    $(".dictionary-stack").css('opacity', 0);
    $(".dictionary-stack").append(' &nbsp; &#8226; &#8226; &#8226; &nbsp; <span class="' +
                                  data[0].archive_url + '">' +
                                  data[0].archive_url + ' ' +
                                  data[0].archive_url + ' [' +
                                  data[0].archive_url + ']</span>');
    clearTimeout(interval);
    interval = setTimeout(function () {
      while ($(this).outerHeight() > +$(this).attr('data-height')) {
        this.textContent = this.textContent.substr(1);
      }
      $(this).css('opacity', 1);
    }.bind($(".dictionary-stack").get(0)), 50);
  });
});
```

```css
.dictionary-stack
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:100px;
  width:100%;
  display: block;
  background:#E6E6E6;
  padding: 20px;
  color:#333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="myBtn">Load Data</button>
<div class="dictionary-stack"></div>
```